# Restricting values in parameters via annotations Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was testing Kotlin annotations and wasn't able to get this seemingly simple code to work

This is my simple annotation

```
@IntDef(1,2)
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class OnlyOneTwo
```

Now I am assuming that if I decorate a value parameter with `@OnlyOneTwo` , that method would raise a compile error if I give it a value like `5` .

I am using this annotation like this

```
fun onlyTakesOneTwos(@OnlyOneTwo input:Int){

}
onlyTakesOneTwos(6) // shouldn't this throw a compile error ?
```

I remember in Java it used to throw an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it is not `Kotlin` compiler which checks for this type of annotation errors, `Android` Lint does, also this might work and preferred over enums in `Java`, but in `Kotlin`, the only way to do these are using `enums`, You can still use `@IntDef` in `Kotlin` to provide suggestions but other values won't give you a compile error. Also with ART, mem footprint for enums are not a big deal, this was also covered in Google IO 2018 while talking about `ART` https://youtu.be/IrMw7MEgADk?t=855